# In Gerrit how to temporarily block/deny submits to a given branch?

Tags: gerrit

It's *possible* to modify access rules to certain branches of a given repository (both via UI and via Gerrit API) to block submits (e.g. in case of emergency maintenance).

However the only way I know to do this requires me to manually reconfigure rules in a every time I have to block modifications on a branch immediately. Because this is cumbersome, error prone and hard to document I'd like to have a "red button" solution instead.

To avoid re-inventing the wheel using [manually written rules](https://git.eclipse.org/r/Documentation/prolog-cookbook.html) or [scripting](https://pypi.org/project/python-gerrit-api/) yet another solution for a problem other people had before I'm asking myself (or rather you) whether there is a to-go method already which stops submits to a faulty branch and similarly easily allows them again.

A solution I'd like to have would allow me to easily run

```
gerrit-set-submit-traffic-light block master
```

in cases of emergency on `master` branch and running

```
gerrit-set-submit-traffic-light allow master
```

to enable submitting again..

Is there such a thing? What would be the straight forward way to do this?

Comment: For a given repository, you can add ref patterns in the access configuration and grant Submit permission to a certain group with "exclusive", so that anyone not in the group cannot submit changes on these branches.

Comment: But I would have to modify those patterns manually each time I want to toggle between a "red' or "green" mode, wouldn't I?

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

All permissions for a repository are maintained in the repository itself, under the `refs/meta/config` ref in the file `project.config`.

If you want to disable the "submit" permission for a given branch, you need to modify that file. E.g., to temporarily restrict the submit permission to members of group `Master-Emergency-Submitters`, you'd add

```
[access "refs/heads/master"]
        submit = group Master-Emergency-Submitters
```

Once the emergency situation is over, you'd remove that entry again.

To perform these changes, all you need to do is to push the updated `project.config` file, which is easily scriptable.

**Option 2**

The Gerrit [hooks](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/hooks/) plugin supports a [`submit`](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/hooks/+/refs/heads/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/hooks.md#submit) hook that can block the submit step. The hook is a simple shell script which you can use to disable commits to your branches depending on some condition.

While the second option is less intrusive, it will still leave the "Submit" button enabled in the GUI (blocking submits *after* the user selected to perform them), which is less nice from a UX point of view.